# artisan command testing Output "+----+----------+------------+----------------------+" was not printed

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to test an artisan command that give as output a db table for a given customer id.
on Laravel 8.

```
php artisan get:report "1"
+----+----------+------------+---------------------+
| id | customer | date       | value               |
+----+----------+------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 1        | 01/04/2015 | EUR 55.201818920353 |
| 5  | 1        | 02/04/2015 | EUR 12.188561617614 |
| 6  | 1        | 02/04/2015 | EUR 1.00            |
| 7  | 1        | 03/04/2015 | EUR 14.050917779273 |
+----+----------+------------+---------------------+
```

So I wrote this unit test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;


class GetReportTest extends TestCase
{
    
    protected $tableHeader=['id', 'customer', 'date','value'];
    protected $rows=[[1,'1','01/04/2015' , 'EUR 55.201818920353'],
                        [5,'1' ,'02/04/2015',' EUR 12.188561617614'],
                        [6,'1','02/04/2015','EUR 1.00' ],
                        [7,'1','03/04/2015','EUR 14.050917779273' ]  ];
  
    
     /** @test */
    public function getReportCommand()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(class_exists(\App\Console\Commands\GetClientReport::class));
    }
    
    /** @test */
    public function itCanGetReport()
    {
        $this->artisan('get:report "1"')->expectsTable($this->tableHeader,$this->rows)
        ->assertExitCode(0);
        $this->assertTrue(true);


    }
    
  
}
```

The first test (getReportCommand()) works and the test is passed.
The second no, and give me this error:

```
⨯ it can get report

  ---

  • Tests\Unit\GetReportTest > it can get report
  Output "+----+----------+------------+----------------------+" was not printed.

  at tests/Unit/GetReportTest.php:29
     25▕     /** @test */
     26▕     public function itCanGetReport()
     27▕     {
     28▕         $this->artisan('get:report "1"')->expectsTable($this->tableHeader,$this->rows)
  ➜  29▕         ->assertExitCode(0);
     30▕                                 
     31▕                                 
     32▕ 
     33▕
```

my questions are:
how can i interact with command output?
is it the right way to execute such type of test?
do I need a function for testing each possible input?

Answer (score -1):

The error `Output "+----+----------+------------+----------------------+" was not printed.` is likely connected to the "length" of the rows. If only one data is longer than in your test, the first line will fail. Can you check that again in your code? Even a space could lead to that issue.